# Customising the "Export Report" / "Export Details" dialog?

Tags: visualforce, data-export, gdpr

We have a number of changes planned to internal and external-facing systems to achieve greater compliance with GDPR. I have been asked to add a message or pop-up whenever personal data is exported from Salesforce, reminding users of the precautions to take.

Is it possible to add text/HTML to the "Export Report" screen (where I am asked to choose an encoding and file format), that appears after I click the "Export Details" button while viewing a report? Is it possible to add a simple alert box on clicking one of the buttons in the export process? Are you aware of an existing app/package to add similar warnings?

I don't think [this kind of hack](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/57/36298) applies, because on the "Export Report" screen, I don't see the left navigation at all.